# What does aw mean?

Tags: meaning, conversation

I have heard somebody saying *aw, shucks*.

- What does that mean?
- In which other cases is the word used?

Comment: Always keep in mind that some awe is awesome, but anything full of awe is awful. (^_^)

Comment: or spelled 'awwww...'; also not to be confused with 'ahhh...'

Comment: Right, if someone shows you their baby and you say "awwww...", you are saying the baby is cute; if you say "ahhh...", you are being evasive :)

Comment: Reminds me of a scene in *George of the Jungle*: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119190/quotes?qt0452429

Comment: @Kosmonaut this distinction has always been confusing to those of us with the cot-caught merger.

Comment: @nohat: Ha, interesting point!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The word "aw" in this case is an interjection with the following definition (from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aw)):

> used to express mild disappointment, gentle entreaty, or real or mock sympathy or sentiment

If something mildly bad (but not too bad) happens to someone else, you can say "aw". (If it is something really bad, then it sounds rude to say "aw".)

Answer (score 2):

It that case *awe* means nothing.  It is a particle.  Kinda like the *oh* in *Oh... that's bad.*

Comment: And it's generally spelled "aw". And in that phrase, it's probably "aw, shucks".

Comment: I am reluctant to say that interjections mean nothing.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: What?! Ah gosh... wow..

Comment: @Kosmonaut Interjections sometimes mean much more than "real" words, as does nonverbal communication.

Answer (score 2):

"Aw, shucks" together form an extremely mild expletive to express disappointment or frustration. Think "Oh, damn" for kindergartners. It's also used to indicate false modesty, something a cartoon character says while blushing after being complimented. It carries a little bit of a rustic, unsophisticated flavor. I've seen it applied to politicians affecting a humble demeanor.